# JavaScript - returning to previous value?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am having just a simple question. I've started with learning javascript.

Currently learning the DOM stuff about HTML content manipulation.

My issue is something like this:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    include("db/config.php");

    mssql_select_db($dbName1, $dbConn);
            $sq = mssql_query("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM LandingPage ORDER BY ID DESC");
    while($s = mssql_fetch_array($sq)) {
        ?>
            <nav id="overlay_box" class="overlay_box_style">
                <div id="overlay_inbound">
                    <a href="#" id="latestEntryForm">Latest Entry</a>
                </div>

                <div id="overlay_outbound">
                    <a href="#" id="msgContentForm">Leave A Message!</a>
                </div>
                <!-- javascript DOM injection @overlay_holder -->
                <div id="overlay_holder" class="overlay_holder_style">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="overlay_title">
                            <p class="overlay_title_style">Latest Entry</p>
                            <p class="overlay_title_style">- <?=$s['Title']?></p><br>
                        </li>
                        <li id="overlay_content">
                            <?=$s['Content'] = substr($s['Content'], 0, 200);?>...
                        </li>
                        <li id="overlay_date">
                            </br>| <?=$s['Date'];?> |<br><?=$s['Author'];?>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

  <?  } ?>


<script type="text/javascript">
$("#msgContentForm").click(function() {
    $("#overlay_holder").load("admin/msgContentForm.php");
    return false;
});
</script>
```

How can I solve this, making it efficient and optimized without the additional "work around" *.php file?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want to switch the two files on click of single button ? Am I getting it right?

Comment: You're saying "My issue is something like this" but then there's just HTML code and a vague question. What's the issue?

Answer (score 1):

My idea is like this:

Use $_GET["mode"] superglobal variable, and allow the values "local" and "whole". This one is used to determine whether you want to load part of the HTML or the whole one.

Then, set conditions to control the output, for example:

```
if($_GET["mode"]=="local"){echo "bla bla bla";}
```

Then, in the ajax URL, change to:

```
$("#overlay_holder").load("admin/latestEntryForm.php?mode=local");
```

Then you would only need to edit one file!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the first file is static except for the content from latestEntryForm.php.  Have the first file include the latestEntryForm.php page in place of the latest entry code. Then you won't be repeating your php code.

Comment: No, note that the two files are doing the same thing. op is trying to have same result with only one file.

Comment: He wants to make it efficient without 'work around' files.  He's got the same code in two places.  If he removed the code from the first place and included it from the second, then the second file becomes essential, not a 'work around'.  It's a proper breakdown of concerns.  He could put it all in one file with if blocks to only render what is requested, but that is even more complicated and spaghetti-like.